# python sparse matrix creation paralellize to speed up

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, mapreduce, sparse-matrix

I am creating a sparse matrix file, by extracting the features from an input file. The input file contains in each row, one film id, and then followed by some feature IDs and that features score.

```
6729792 4:0.15568 8:0.198796 9:0.279261 13:0.17829 24:0.379707
```

the first number is the ID of the film, and then the value to the left of the colon is feature ID and the value to the right is the score of that feature.
Each line represents one film, and the number of `feature:score` pairs vary from one film to another.

here is how I construct my sparse matrix.

```
import sys
import os
import os.path
import time
import numpy as np
from Film import Film
import scipy
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix, csr_matrix, rand

def sparseCreate(self, Debug):

    a = rand(self.total_rows, self.total_columns, format='csr')


    l, m = a.shape[0], a.shape[1]


    f = tb.open_file("sparseFile.h5", 'w')

    filters = tb.Filters(complevel=5, complib='blosc')
    data_matrix = f.create_carray(f.root, 'data', tb.Float32Atom(), shape=(l, m), filters=filters)

    index_film = 0
    input_data = open('input_file.txt', 'r')

    for line in input_data:
        my_line = np.array(line.split())

        id_film = my_line[0]
        my_line = np.core.defchararray.split(my_line[1:], ":")
        self.data_matrix_search_normal[str(id_film)] = index_film
        self.data_matrix_search_reverse[index_film] = str(id_film)

        for element in my_line:

            if int(element[0]) in self.selected_features:
                column = self.index_selected_feature[str(element[0])]
                data_matrix[index_film, column] = float(element[1])

        index_film += 1
    self.selected_matrix = data_matrix

    json.dump(self.data_matrix_search_reverse,
              open(os.path.join(self.output_path, "data_matrix_search_reverse.json"), 'wb'),
              sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    my_films = Film(
        self.selected_matrix, self.data_matrix_search_reverse, self.path_doc, self.output_path)
    x_matrix_unique = self.selected_matrix[:, :]
    r_matrix_unique = np.asarray(x_matrix_unique)
    f.close()

    return my_films
```

### Question:

I feel that this function is too slow on big datasets, and it takes too long to calculate.

**How can I improve and accelerate it? maybe using MapReduce? What is wrong in this function that makes it too slow?**

Answer (score 0):

IO + conversions (from str, to str, even 2 times to str of the same var, etc) + splits + explicit loops. Btw, there is CSV python module which may be used to parse your input file, you can experiment with it (I suppose you use space as delimiter). Also I' see you convert `element[0]` to int/str which is bad - you create many tmp. object. If you call this function several times, you may to try to reuse some internal objects (array?). Also, you can try to implement it in another style: with map or  list comprehension, but experiments are needed...
General idea of Python code optimization is to avoid explicit Python byte-code execution and to prefer native/C Python functions (for anything). And sure try to solve so many conversions. Also if input file is yours you can format it to fixed length of fields - this helps you to avoid split/parse totally (only string indexing).

Comment: i can't change the input file unfortunately, could you suggest an example code improvement? what exactly and which part of the code should be changed? how about mapreduce?